# Get title of a navigation bar button item in swift?

Tags: swift4

I am not able to get navigation bar button item, when I created action outlet.Here is my code

```
@IBAction func rightBarButtonItemDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
    print(sender.title)
}
```

but title is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    @IBAction func rightBarButtonItemDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
       let barButton = sender as? UIBarButtonItem
       if let title = barButton?.title {
         print(title)
       }
     }
```